# Building an app, root directory doesn't contain/auto-create a .forceignore file

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm trying to pull metadata while ignoring profiles changes, but my root directory in my current project does not contain/auto-create a .forceignore file, how should go about troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a new file. It's a plain text file similar to a `.gitignore` file. Comments start with a `#` and go to the end of a line, all other lines contain standard file globs. You can read more in [How to Exclude Source When Syncing or Converting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_exclude_source.htm). Normally, this file is only created once when you use `force:project:create` in a later version. You can try calling `force:project:create` on an existing project, but be aware that changes may be overwritten if you do this.